How to tell TypeScript that a variable must be defined if another one is true?
I have basic react-query code:
export const useDataQuery = ({
  dataId,
  enabled = Boolean(dataId),
}: {
  dataId?: string;
  enabled?: boolean;
}) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: [DATA_ID, dataId],
    enabled,
    queryFn: async () => {
      const data = await getData(dataId);
      return data;
    },
  });
};

In the above code:

queryFn won't run if enabled is falsy
enabled is always true if dataId is defined
ts still thinks that dataId might be undefined in await getData(dataId)

Is there an easy way to bind these variables together?
I know that using dataId! or throwing an error will fix that:
if (!dataId) throw new Error('Missing dataId')

But I'm looking for a less hacky solution.

Discriminate a union? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

You could use a type union to achieve this:
type Query = { enabled: true, dataId: number } | { enabled: false, dataId: undefined };

export const useDataQuery = (query: Query) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: [DATA_ID, query.dataId],
    enabled: query.enabled,
    queryFn: async () => {
        if (query.enabled) {
            const data = await getData(query.dataId);

            return data;
        }
    },
  });
};

By doing it this way, for any code within an if (query.enabled), typescript will know that dataId is of type number.
This would allow you to put the if anywhere that makes sense for your use case, although I have put it inside the queryFn for now.

This works because it's a discriminated union, so you might want to note that and link to the doc.

This is correct in TypeScript, but it will complain as queryFn can't return void. You must throw or return undefined when the condition doesn't fulfill. Or use the skipToken approach as my answer explains.

@AhmedAbdelbaset I am not familiar with the exact library, i was answering more focussed on the typescript question that was asked :)

TypeScript flow analysis can't know that you pass dataId to enabled. As of @tanstack/react-query v5.25, TanStack Query provides skipToken to skip the query based on a condition.
import { useQuery, skipToken } from "@tanstack/react-query";

export const useDataQuery = ({
  dataId,
  enabled = Boolean(dataId),
}: {
  dataId?: string;
  enabled?: boolean;
}) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: [DATA_ID, dataId],
    enabled,
    queryFn: !enabled ? skipToken : async () => {
      const data = await getData(dataId);
      return data;
    },
  });
};

This way, enabled inside the queryFn is true not boolean. If want to make dataId non-undefinedable, you can do this:
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: [DATA_ID, dataId],
    enabled,
    queryFn: !dataId ? skipToken : async () => {
      // dataId is not undefined or null
      const data = await getData(dataId);
      return data;
    },
  });

Read more at the Docs and the maintainer blog
